# Nginx block from referrer

Tags: nginx, spam-prevention, referrer-spam

I need block all http connections, who have referrer click2dad.net.
I write in mysite.conf:

```
 location / {
            valid_referers ~.*http://click2dad\.net.*;
            if ($invalid_referer = ''){
                    return 403;
            }
            try_files       $uri    $uri/   /index.php?$args;
    }
```

But i still see in nginx logs:

```
HTTP/1.1" 200 26984 "http://click2dad.net/view/VUhfCE4ugTsb0SoKerhgMvPXcmXszU"
```

200, not 403

As it is correct to block all clients from the click2dad.net ?

Comment: Thanks all, i just deny open iframe in nginx config, and click2dad do not may get my site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It should be noted that an expression will be matched against the text starting after the “http://” or “https://”
>   http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_referer_module.html

Correct config:

```
 location / {
            valid_referers click2dad.net*;
            if ($invalid_referer = ''){
                    return 403;
            }
            try_files       $uri    $uri/   /index.php?$args;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show full nginx config? may be work over location or something else.

Comment: Add asterisk. I tested this config on my server (with over domain) and it return 403.

Answer (score 21):

`valid_referers` solution works but, to me personally, it's hard to maintain a long blacklist that way. An alternative solution is to use `ngx_http_map_module` module. Under ubuntu 14.04 nginx distribution, you would make an /etc/nginx/blacklist.conf file:

```
# /etc/nginx/blacklist.conf

map $http_referer $bad_referer {
    hostnames;

    default                           0;

    # Put regexes for undesired referers here
    "~social-buttons.com"             1;
    "~semalt.com"                     1;
    "~kambasoft.com"                  1;
    "~savetubevideo.com"              1;
    "~descargar-musica-gratis.net"    1;
    "~7makemoneyonline.com"           1;
    "~baixar-musicas-gratis.com"      1;
    "~iloveitaly.com"                 1;
    "~ilovevitaly.ru"                 1;
    "~fbdownloader.com"               1;
    "~econom.co"                      1;
    "~buttons-for-website.com"        1;
    "~buttons-for-your-website.com"   1;
    "~srecorder.co"                   1;
    "~darodar.com"                    1;
    "~priceg.com"                     1;
    "~blackhatworth.com"              1;
    "~adviceforum.info"               1;
    "~hulfingtonpost.com"             1;
    "~best-seo-solution.com"          1;
    "~googlsucks.com"                 1;
    "~theguardlan.com"                1;
    "~i-x.wiki"                       1;
    "~buy-cheap-online.info"          1;
    "~Get-Free-Traffic-Now.com"       1;
}
```

Then include it in your /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file:

```
# /etc/nginx/nginx.conf


    http {
    # ...

      include blacklist.conf;

    # ...

    }
```

Having done that, you can check for `$bad_referer` condition in your nginx site:

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite.conf

server {
  # ...

  if ($bad_referer) { 
    return 444; 
  } 

  # ...
}
```

And to ensure that this stuff works, you can execute a similar command in your shell:

```
$ curl --referer http://www.social-buttons.com https://example.org
```

... which should give you:

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

I wrote a blog post on this solution here https://fadeit.dk/blog/2015/04/22/nginx-referer-spam-blacklist/ .

Comment: These regex's will match `other-social-buttons.com`, `google.com/page-about-social-buttons.com`, `social-buttons.com.uk`, and **not only** `social-buttons.com`. To play safe you can use `"~*^https?://(www.)?social-buttons\.com(/.*)?$" 1;` (which will test for a referer starting with `https` or `http` and an optional `www.`. It starts with `~*` which means it's a case insensitive regex. You should escape dots like this `\.` It ends with `(/.*)?$` which excludes other domains. When I tested the `hostnames;` didn't have any effect (nginx/1.14.0), but you **can** use them in a `$http_host` map.

Comment: The link at the bottom to the blogpost is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this config:

```
 location / {
        valid_referers ~click2dad.net;
        if ($invalid_referer){
                return 403;
        }
        try_files       $uri    $uri/   /index.php?$args;
}
```

Anyway, the right answer is just in this document.
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_referer_module.html